# I came across this book called "Right the First Time", about PCB design. I came across this sentence, and I am just mad confused about what it means

Tags: voltage, pcb, pcb-design, books

> It is worth noting that the usable signal in all cases is a voltage waveform. This is true whether the signal is RF, microwave, analog or digital. It is also true no matter what type of driver is being used. It is true even if the signal source is described as operating in the “current mode.” As will be seen later, it is not possible to send “voltage” waveforms from one place to another. In order to deliver a voltage waveform it is necessary to create
> and send energy in the form of an electromagnetic wave, either down a transmission line or through space.

Can anyone explain this? Much appreciated!

Comment: Mustafa Tahir -Hi, To comply with the [site rule](/help/referencing) for content copied into a post from elsewhere, can you please [edit] your question and add the book's title, author(s), publisher & the page number(s) for that quoted passage? Thanks.

Comment: Frankly this sounds like someone wanting to overgeneralize to the point of self-contradiction.  The idea is probably in the context of PCB tracks as conducting elements, but since you can print circuits like capacitors and inductors for microwave usage on a PCB, this sounds dubious at best with the explicitly stated generality.

Comment: More context is needed.

Comment: This sentence does make some sense. The author first asserts that information is carried on a voltage waveform, however, getting that voltage waveform from a source circuit to a receiver circuit requires the transfer of *energy*. Meaning, you need to take into account both the voltage AND current, regardless of the link medium, whether it be in an EM wave or down a TL.

Comment: It says "As will be seen later..." Your quote comes right at the first page of chapter 2 and is just a set-up for what comes later. Read on and, if need be, come back and re-read this later on. It will mean more to you then.

Comment: Mustafa Tahir - Hi, I see you have returned and commented on an answer below. However you have not made the edit to add the [required](/help/referencing) citation/reference for the material you copied into your question. Eventually, someone else will do their best to add it for you, *but* it will be noted that *you* did not follow the site rules. I strongly recommend that you quickly add the citation/reference which *you* are required to add, before someone else has to do it for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When potential anywhere in a system changes, or current anywhere changes, this really only implies that charges have moved. This movement, or perturbation, results in waves that travel through the conductor, in the same way that an acoustic wave travels through some medium. That is, there are fronts of charge compression and rarefaction that propagate outwards from the initial perturbation, waves which travel, reflect, refract and diffract just as acoustic waves do, or water ripples on a pond.

What we call potential at some point is really just an average potential energy level of charges there, the result of the superposition of all such waves interfering at that point. Similarly, there may be some general migration of charges in some direction there, which we call current.

In other words, the actual mechanism at work leading to these phenomena we call current and voltage is really just an incredibly complicated dance of travelling waves of charge rarefaction and compression, all interfering and superimposing on each other.

In any physical system, electrical systems included, energy is delivered from place to place ("work is done") on/by these waves. Any individual wave is a "packet" of energy, travelling, reflecting, refracting, diffracting (as all waves do), until it encounters something that absorbs that energy, and attenuates or extinguishes the wave. This underlying dance of waves is immeasurably complicated, but together they produce remarkably organised and predictable conditions at a larger scale, which we quantify and measure as voltage and current.

Therefore, while you may consider that a wire is sharing/carrying some potential between two physically distinct places, or providing a path for current, these two phenomena are mere abstractions, conveniently quantifiable average behaviour of huge numbers of charges on a large scale. The true mechanism going on behind the scenes is waves, which carry energy and "do work", and *everything* is energy in one form or another.

Comment: Thank you Sire!